# How can I keep Skype from telling me people's birthdays?

Tags: notifications, skype

I use Skype on my Windows phone as well as on my tablet and various other devices. Only the Windows Phone variant lights up with a notification when it is someone's birthday. This is just not information I need about most of the people on my Skype list. Either I know (my mother) or I don't care (a business contact I had one call with once and have left in my contacts list.) The handful of people I speak to regularly but don't already know their birthdays is not enough for me to want this feature.

But I can't turn it off! I suspect I turned it off on my desktop and Metro versions of Skype, since they don't tell me. I don't see it as a setting on the phone though. Can it be turned off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you send the message "/nobday" into any chat, it will disable birthday notifications for that entire client.  Nothing will actually be sent to other party.

Comment: Will the person know I have started a chat with them? And don't want to know about their birthday?

Comment: Excellent question.  I have clarified in the answer.

Comment: I did this and Skype replied `Birthday notifications disabled` which is a very good sign. The person I chose says they didn't get any kind of message from me, also a good sign.